# AttributeError: 'Socket' object has no attribute 'recv'

Tags: django, socket.io, gevent

I'm trying to get this example(https://github.com/sontek/django-tictactoe/tree/master/small_tictactoe) for gevent-socketio running, but but I get this very strange error:

```
Internal Server Error: /socket.io/1/websocket/49318546715
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/User/Envs/Echtzeit/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/User/Envs/Echtzeit/small_tictactoe/apps/core/views.py", line 37, in socketio
message = socketio.recv()
AttributeError: 'Socket' object has no attribute 'recv'
```

But I found    `socketio.recv()`  used in other examples an documentations as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is two year old. Since that api was changed.As you can see now there is no recv method exist. You can check method that exists [here](https://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/namespace.html#dealing-with-incoming-data) :